# wxWidget app hangs after source ID not found

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxWidget (3.2.1) app that runs fine on MacOS (12.6.3) but hangs randomly on Centos 8.2. The hang *always* occurs after the following message is printed by the app

Source ID xxxx was not found when attempting to remove it

I have tried running the app via gdb but I'm unable to locate source of the above msg.

The app has a frame class that handles all the GUI related stuff, and a separate thread that handles all network related stuff. The frame class has a listener for network connections. When a client sends data, the frame class gets notified and places the socket into a queue that is read by the network thread, which then processes the incoming data. Similarly, when the frame class wants to write to the client, it places the data into a write queue and the network class writes the data to the client.

Whenever the network thread completed receiving a packet, it notifies the GUI thread using the following code

```
wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, ID_ProcClientCmd);
event.SetPayload(pkt_info);
wxQueueEvent(parent, event.Clone());
```

In the GUI thread

```
    // in .h file
    wxMutex* mutexReadQ;
    wxMutex* mutexWriteQ;

    // in .CPP file
    mutexReadQ       = new wxMutex;
    mutexWriteQ      = new wxMutex;

    // setup Network thread
    networkThread = new NetworkThread(this, mutexKeepRunning,mutexReadQ, mutexWriteQ, &keepRunning);
    networkThread->Run();

   // When GUI thread is notified that a socket has incoming data
   mutexReadQ->Lock();
   networkThread->la_readQ.push(skt);
   mutexReadQ->Unlock();

   // when GUI thread wants to write to skt
    mutexWriteQ->Lock();
    networkThread->la_writeQ.push(pi);
    mutexWriteQ->Unlock();
```

In the Network thread

```
    // in .h file
    wxMutex*      mutexReadQ;
    wxMutex*      mutexWriteQ;

    // in .cpp file

    // constructor
NetworkThread::NetworkThread(wxEvtHandler* p_parent, wxMutex* p_mutexKeepRunning, wxMutex* p_mutexReadQ, wxMutex* p_mutexWriteQ,
bool* p_keepRunning)
{
    this->parent           = p_parent;
    this->mutexKeepRunning = p_mutexKeepRunning;
    this->keepRunning      = p_keepRunning;
    this->mutexReadQ       = p_mutexReadQ;
    this->mutexWriteQ      = p_mutexWriteQ;
}

void* NetworkThread::Entry()
{
    wxSocketBase*   readSkt;
    PKT_INFO*       pkt_info;

    while (1)
    {
        // check if app wants this thread to terminate
        mutexKeepRunning->Lock();
        if (*keepRunning == false) {
            mutexKeepRunning->Unlock();
            return NULL;
        }
        mutexKeepRunning->Unlock();

        readSkt  = NULL;
        pkt_info = NULL;

        // process read requests
        mutexReadQ->Lock();
        if (!la_readQ.empty()) {
            readSkt = la_readQ.front();
            la_readQ.pop();
        }
        mutexReadQ->Unlock();
        if (readSkt)
            readFromSkt(readSkt);

        // process write requests
        mutexWriteQ->Lock();
        if (!la_writeQ.empty()) {
            pkt_info = la_writeQ.front();
            la_writeQ.pop();
        }
        mutexWriteQ->Unlock();
        if (pkt_info)
            writeToSkt(pkt_info);

        // nothing to do if both Qs are empty
        if ((readSkt == NULL) && (pkt_info == NULL)) {
            wxMilliSleep(THREAD_SLEEP_DUR);
            continue;
        }
    } // while (1)
}
```

I have a minimal app that reproduces the above problem as soon as it is run. There are two parts to this app. One is the wx_widget code and the other is an echo_client that uses sockets. This is the code for wxWidget app

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/socket.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char uchar;

#define MIN(_x, _y)         (((_x) < (_y)) ? (_x) : (_y))

#define NET_PKT_SIZE    (1024 * 1024)
#define NETWORK_PORT    54321

enum AppIDs
{
    ID_SktServer = wxID_LAST + 1,
    ID_SktClient,
    ID_ProcClientCmd
};

typedef struct
{
    wxSocketBase*   skt;
    uchar*          buf;
    int             length;
} PKT_INFO;

class NetworkThread : public wxThread
{
    public:
    NetworkThread(wxEvtHandler* p_parent, wxMutex* p_mutexKeepRunning, wxMutex* p_mutexReadQ, wxMutex* p_mutexWriteQ,
                  bool* p_keepRunning);
    virtual void* Entry();

    queue<wxSocketBase*> la_readQ;  // locked access
    queue<PKT_INFO*>     la_writeQ; // locked access

    wxEvtHandler* parent;
    wxMutex*      mutexKeepRunning;
    wxMutex*      mutexReadQ;
    wxMutex*      mutexWriteQ;
    bool*         keepRunning;

    private:
    void readFromSkt(wxSocketBase* skt);
    void writeToSkt(PKT_INFO* pkt_info);
    int  pktSendCtr;
};


NetworkThread::NetworkThread(wxEvtHandler* p_parent, wxMutex* p_mutexKeepRunning,
                             wxMutex* p_mutexReadQ, wxMutex* p_mutexWriteQ,
                             bool* p_keepRunning)
{
    this->parent           = p_parent;
    this->mutexKeepRunning = p_mutexKeepRunning;
    this->keepRunning      = p_keepRunning;
    this->mutexReadQ       = p_mutexReadQ;
    this->mutexWriteQ      = p_mutexWriteQ;
    pktSendCtr             = 1;
}

void* NetworkThread::Entry()
{
    wxSocketBase*   readSkt;
    PKT_INFO*       pkt_info;

    while (1)
    {
        // check if app wants this thread to terminate
        mutexKeepRunning->Lock();
        if (*keepRunning == false) {
            mutexKeepRunning->Unlock();
            return NULL;
        }
        mutexKeepRunning->Unlock();

        readSkt  = NULL;
        pkt_info = NULL;

        // process read requests
        mutexReadQ->Lock();
            if (!la_readQ.empty()) {
                readSkt = la_readQ.front();
                la_readQ.pop();
            }
        mutexReadQ->Unlock();

        if (readSkt)
            readFromSkt(readSkt);

        // process write requests
        mutexWriteQ->Lock();
            if (!la_writeQ.empty()) {
                pkt_info = la_writeQ.front();
                la_writeQ.pop();
            }
        mutexWriteQ->Unlock();
        if (pkt_info)
            writeToSkt(pkt_info);

        // nothing to do if both Qs are empty
        if ((readSkt == NULL) && (pkt_info == NULL)) {
            #ifdef USE_YIELD
            Yield();
            #else
            wxMilliSleep(25);
            #endif
            continue;
        }
    } // while (1)
}

void NetworkThread::readFromSkt(wxSocketBase* skt)
{
    PKT_INFO* pkt_info;

    unsigned char*  buf;
    int     bytesToRead;
    int     bytesRead;
    int     index;

    if (!skt)
        return;

    // allocate buffer
    buf = new unsigned char[NET_PKT_SIZE];
    if (!buf) {
        wxPrintf("readFromSkt: system out of memory\n");
        skt->Close();
        return;
    }

    // ensure we really have some data to read
    skt->Peek(buf, 1);
    if (skt->LastCount() == 0) {
        wxPrintf("readFromSkt: nothign to read\n");
        return;
    }

    bytesToRead = NET_PKT_SIZE;
    index = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        skt->Read(&buf[index], bytesToRead);
        if (skt->Error()) {
            skt->Close();
            delete buf;
            wxPrintf("networkThread:readFromSkt: read error, closing conxn\n");
            return;
        }
        bytesRead = skt->LastReadCount();
        bytesToRead -= bytesRead;
        if (bytesToRead <= 0)
            break;
        index += bytesRead;
    }

     // setup pkt info so we can dispatch it to GUI thread
    pkt_info = new PKT_INFO;
    if (!pkt_info) {
        wxPrintf("readFromSkt: system out of memory\n");
        skt->Close();
        delete buf;
        return;
    }
    pkt_info->skt = skt;
    pkt_info->buf = buf;
    pkt_info->length = NET_PKT_SIZE;

    // let main thread process payload
    if (parent != NULL)
    {
        wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, ID_ProcClientCmd);
        event.SetPayload(pkt_info);
        wxQueueEvent(parent, event.Clone());
    }
}

void NetworkThread::writeToSkt(PKT_INFO* pkt_info)
{
    wxSocketBase*   skt;
    uchar*          buf;
    int             bytesToWrite;
    int             index;
    int             writeCount;

    if (!pkt_info || !pkt_info->skt || !pkt_info->buf || (pkt_info->length <= 0))
        return;

    skt = pkt_info->skt;
    buf = pkt_info->buf;
    bytesToWrite = pkt_info->length;

    index = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        // write only 1400 bytes at a time so we can cross router boundaries
        skt->Write(&buf[index], MIN(bytesToWrite, 1400));
        if (skt->Error())
        {
            int se = skt->LastError();
            if (se == wxSOCKET_WOULDBLOCK) {
                continue;
            }
            skt->Close();
            wxPuts("NetworkThread::writeToSkt: write error, closing conxn");
            break;
        }

        writeCount = skt->LastWriteCount();
        bytesToWrite -= writeCount;
        if (bytesToWrite <= 0)
            break;
        index += writeCount;
    }

    delete pkt_info->buf;
    delete pkt_info;

    wxPrintf("Sent pkt %d\n", pktSendCtr++);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
  public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

class Button : public wxFrame
{
    public:
    Button(const wxString& title);
    void onProcessMsg(PKT_INFO* data);

    private:
    wxSocketServer* sktServer;
    wxMutex* mutexKeepRunning;
    wxMutex* mutexReadQ;
    wxMutex* mutexWriteQ;
    NetworkThread* networkThread;
    wxButton* btnWidget;

    bool keepRunning;
    int  pktRecvdCtr;

    void OnBtnClicked(wxCommandEvent & event);
    void OnServerSktEvent(wxSocketEvent &event);
    void OnClientSktEvent(wxSocketEvent &event);
    void OnProcessClientCmd(wxThreadEvent &event);
    void SendDataToNetworkThread(wxSocketBase* skt);
};

Button::Button(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(270, 150))
{
    wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

    btnWidget = new wxButton(panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Start server"),
                                    wxPoint(20, 20));

    Connect(wxID_EXIT, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,
            wxCommandEventHandler(Button::OnBtnClicked));

    btnWidget->SetFocus();
    Centre();
    keepRunning = true;
    pktRecvdCtr = 1;
}

void Button::OnBtnClicked(wxCommandEvent & WXUNUSED(event))
{
    btnWidget->Enable(false);

    wxIPV4address addr;
    addr.Service(NETWORK_PORT);
    sktServer = new wxSocketServer(addr, wxSOCKET_REUSEADDR | wxSOCKET_NOWAIT);
    if (!sktServer->IsOk()) {
        wxPrintf("Could not listen on port %d\n", NETWORK_PORT);
        return ;
    }

    // setup event handler and subscribe to connection events
    sktServer->SetEventHandler(*this, ID_SktServer);
    sktServer->SetNotify(wxSOCKET_CONNECTION_FLAG);
    sktServer->Notify(true);

    // start thread to handle network traffic
    mutexKeepRunning = new wxMutex;
    mutexReadQ       = new wxMutex;
    mutexWriteQ      = new wxMutex;
    keepRunning      = true;

    Bind(wxEVT_SOCKET, &Button::OnServerSktEvent, this, ID_SktServer);
    Bind(wxEVT_SOCKET, &Button::OnClientSktEvent, this, ID_SktClient);
    Bind(wxEVT_THREAD, &Button::OnProcessClientCmd, this, ID_ProcClientCmd);

    networkThread = new NetworkThread(this->GetEventHandler(),
                            mutexKeepRunning, mutexReadQ, mutexWriteQ,
                            &keepRunning);
    networkThread->Run();
}

void Button::OnServerSktEvent(wxSocketEvent &event)
{
    if (event.GetSocketEvent() != wxSOCKET_CONNECTION) {
        wxPrintf("Got unknown socket event from sktServer\n");
        return;
    }

    // use non blocking accept to grab new connection
    wxSocketBase *skt = sktServer->Accept(false);
    wxPrintf("Client connected\n");

    skt->SetEventHandler(*this, ID_SktClient);
    skt->SetNotify(wxSOCKET_INPUT_FLAG | wxSOCKET_LOST_FLAG);
    skt->Notify(true);
}

void Button::OnClientSktEvent(wxSocketEvent &event)
{
    wxSocketBase *skt = event.GetSocket();
    skt->SetFlags(wxSOCKET_NOWAIT); // make it non blocking

    switch (event.GetSocketEvent())
    {
    case wxSOCKET_INPUT:
        mutexReadQ->Lock();
            networkThread->la_readQ.push(skt);
        mutexReadQ->Unlock();
        break;

    case wxSOCKET_OUTPUT:
        wxPrintf("OnClientSktEvent: got output data\n");
        break;

    case wxSOCKET_LOST:
        wxPrintf("OnClientSktEvent: client disconnected\n");
        break;

    default:
        wxPrintf("OnClientSktEvent: Unknown event: %d\n", event.GetSocketEvent());
    }
}

void Button::OnProcessClientCmd(wxThreadEvent &event)
{
    PKT_INFO* pi = event.GetPayload<PKT_INFO *>();
    wxSocketBase* skt;

    if (!pi) {
        return;
    }
    skt = pi->skt;

    wxPrintf("Recv pkt %d\n", pktRecvdCtr++);

    // delete pkt_info
    delete pi->buf;
    delete pi;

    SendDataToNetworkThread(skt);
}

void Button::SendDataToNetworkThread(wxSocketBase* skt)
{
    PKT_INFO* pi = new PKT_INFO;
    if (!pi) {
        wxPrintf("System out of memory\n");
        return;
    }

    pi->buf = new unsigned char[NET_PKT_SIZE];
    if (!pi->buf) {
        delete pi;
        wxPrintf("System out of memory\n");
        return;
    }
    pi->length  = NET_PKT_SIZE;
    pi->skt     = skt;

    memset(pi->buf, 0x55, NET_PKT_SIZE);

    mutexWriteQ->Lock();
        networkThread->la_writeQ.push(pi);
    mutexWriteQ->Unlock();
}

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{

    Button *btnapp = new Button(wxT("Button"));
    btnapp->Show(true);

    return true;
}
```

And this is the echo_client code which can be compiled like this: gcc echo_client.c -o echo_client

You must first run the wxWidget app, click on the Start Server button, then run the echo client with he IP address of the system on which wxWidget app is running

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define NET_PKT_SIZE    (1024 * 1024)
#define NETWORK_PORT    54321

char sendBuf[NET_PKT_SIZE];
char recvBuf[NET_PKT_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    unsigned char pattern = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int count;
    int bytesSent;
    int bytesRecvd;
    int recvCounter = 0;
    int sendCounter = 0;
    int sockfd;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: echo_server <IP address>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(NETWORK_PORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

    if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("error creating socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("couldn't connect to server\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("connected to the server\n");

    while (1)
    {
        // send a pkt
        memset(sendBuf, pattern++, NET_PKT_SIZE);
        count = NET_PKT_SIZE;
        index = 0;

        while (1)
        {
            bytesSent = send(sockfd, &sendBuf[index], count, 0);
            if (bytesSent < 0) {
                perror("error writing to server");
                return 1;
            }
            if (bytesSent == 0) {
                perror("write error");
                return 1;
            }
            index += bytesSent;
            count -= bytesSent;
            if (count <= 0)
                break;
        }
        printf("wrote %d packets\n", ++sendCounter);

        // recv pkt
        count = NET_PKT_SIZE;
        index = 0;

        while (1)
        {
            bytesRecvd = recv(sockfd, &recvBuf[index], count, 0);
            if (bytesRecvd < 0) {
                perror("error reading from server");
                return 1;
            }
            index += bytesRecvd;
            count -= bytesRecvd;
            if (count <= 0)
                break;
        }
        printf("recvd %d packets\n", ++recvCounter);
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is the application being signed by Apple?

Comment: No, it has not been signed by Apple. It is running fine on Mac, but having issues on Linux (Centos as well as Ubuntu)

Comment: are you running Debug build?Are accessing any GUI from the secondary thread?

Comment: I am not accessing GUI from network thread. This is how I built wxWidgets
../configure --disable-shared --with-gtk --enable-debug

Comment: are you testing on the same machine you did the build? Do you gave proper locking  implemented? Are you using wxWidgets thread class or standard C++ one?

Comment: I'm testing on the same machine where I built wxWidgets and my app. I tried running my app with strace and it worked just fine!!!! Whenever network thread completes receiving data, it notifies the GUI thread using a wxThreadEvent. I have updated the original post with the code. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm using wxThread thread class

Comment: as a test can you try without --disable-shared? You are on Linux and the official way to build it is with shared option. Also, you didn't answer the question about locking...

Comment: I have updated the post to include my locking code. I tried building wxWidgets with shared options, but now the app won't run because it does not find the following libraries, and they are not available in the Centos 8 repo. libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0, libwx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0, libwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2.so.0, libwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0, libwx_baseu_xml-3.2.so.0, libwx_baseu_net-3.2.so.0, libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0

Comment: is this you actual code? Does Read() call successfully reads all available data? Does Write() writes all of it successfully? The key word in both cases is `ALL`... I presume you know the protocol you are talking with remote. Can you compare what you expect with what you read?

Comment: this is my actual code. Normally ALL data is sent and received. At the point of hang, data has come from the remote client, network thread has received ALL the data and notified the GUI thread. But the GUI thread does not see the event. At the point of hang, if I mouse over a button, instead of showing the tool tip, it displays some random part of the GUI.

Comment: can you put some printf's in the code to see what is going wrong?  It definitly looks like an interlock right now...

Comment: I have been testing with prints. One thing I've observed is that when the apps hangs,   it starts using more and more memory till Linux OOM comes along and kills the app.

Comment: yes but we are interested at which point it hangs...

Comment: I put prints in all my functions and none of them is called when the hang occurs. All functions complete successfully. In the network thread, I also changed wxQueueEvent to CallAfter(), but that did not make any difference

Comment: you do use same mutexRead and mutexWrite in both threads, correct? For the text can you move unlocking socket below `readFromSkt(readSkt);/writeToSkt(pkt_info);`?

Comment: correct, I'm using the same mutexes in both threads. I unlocked the mutexes after readFromSkt() and writeToSkt() completed, but it did not make any difference

Comment: Can you put the printf's inside the read and write of the socket and check whether the read and write returns the stuff you expect it to return and whether there is no interlocks there?

Comment: I put prints inside my skt read/write and also validated the data. I also put some wxMilliSleep() for testing. That too did not help. I moved all skt IO code to GUI thread and the app does not hang. So it looks like there is some issue in inter process communication. I rechecked that I'm always locking the queues before accessing them. BTW, I'm allocating memory in network thread, passing it to GUI thread using CallAfter(), accessing it in GUI thread and when done deleting the memory in GUI thread. Is that ok?

Comment: what we can do is this: run the program as usual and when it hangs - run gdb and attach it to that process. See where the "bt" points to. It definitely looks like you didn't use locking/unlocking correctly.

Comment: I have posted gdb bt in the main post. I also wrote a small wxWidget program with one GUI thread and one NetworkThread thread that exchange data b/w the two threads using queues and locks and that program runs fine without hanging.

Comment: Definitely looks like thread interlock.

Comment: while debugging, I observed that while socket IO is in progress, if I press the control key on the keyboard, the app immediately displays several of the following msgs and hangs: Source ID xxx was not found when attempting to remove it

Comment: I wrote a small test app that does socket IO and hangs  immediately. How can I share this code with you?

Comment: you can put the source in line in your OP  just make sure it is really minimal. You are building it on Linux with wx version 3.2 latest?

Comment: I have put the code for wxWidget app and echo_client in the OP and also instructions on how to build and run the echo_client. Igor, thanks a lot for all your help with this issue. On Linux, all my testing has been done on wxWidgets 3.2.1

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the problem with my minimal code?